# Django oscar paypal not working

Tags: django, paypal, django-oscar

so I am trying to set up [django-oscar-paypal](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal) with django-oscar. So, everything works fine, the paypal express checkout page shows correctly, then it redirects back to the store and when i click the place order button, it redirects to an empty basket, with no transaction being recorded in the dashboard, except for the express dashboard, which shows success. My guess is there is a session loss, or I need to edit the checkout [view](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/sandbox/apps/checkout/views.py) somehow for it to post the request, but i can't find anywhere on how to do that, and copying the one from the sandbox isn't helpful. If anybody managed to make it work I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Well I'm trying to integrate django-oscar-paypal into my django-oscar at the moment, and have absolutely zero clue how to do it. I assumed it would be plugin and play, but the instructions page isn't even remotely up to date for it. 

Perhaps if you could help me get to where you are now, I could help solve the rest with you. Then once it's working I'm going to either do a blog entry on this, or doc pull request. Because it's currently almost unusable and a candidate for "screw it lets move to Rails".